UE5 Editor doesn’t automatically open Rider EAP IDE

I tried both "Rider" and "Rider Uproject" options
When I double click on C++ class or trying Tools -> Open Rider in UE5 Editor I just see this notification in the left bottom corner:

but nothing is happen
When I switch to Visual Studio everything works fine
Here is some information about my programs:



Name
Version




Windows
10 (22H2)


Rider EAP
2024.2 EAP 3 build 242.16677.30


Unreal Engine
5.4.2






Can someone please help me? I will glad to provide any additional information which you need

The answer of Rider stuff (Alexander Pirogov):
As a super hacky-hack for the time being, you can do next:

Copy RiderSourceCodeAccess plugin from the Engine into the Game/Plugins folder

Remove Binaries and Intermediate folders from a new location

In RiderSourceCodeAccess.cpp, swap
FProcHandle Proc = FPlatformProcess::CreateProc(*PlatformAppAndArgs.App, *PlatformAppAndArgs.Args, true, true, false, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);

with
FPlatformProcess::PushDllDirectory(nullptr);
FProcHandle Proc = FPlatformProcess::CreateProc(*PlatformAppAndArgs.App, *PlatformAppAndArgs.Args, true, true, false, nullptr, 0,
                                                nullptr, nullptr);
FPlatformProcess::PopDllDirectory(TEXT(""));



P.S. In my case the file named as RiderSourceCodeAccessor.cpp but I think it is just a typo
